# WPF KeyEventArgs second argument is null

Tags: wpf, keyboard, keyeventargs

```
KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, keyData);
```

Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource is null and program stop working. I tried also:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
System.Windows.PresentationSource source = System.Windows.PresentationSource.FromVisual(mw);
KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, source, 0, keyData);
```

But still null, I cannot replace mw to this, because code is in different file class.

I'm trying to catch keyboard from other windows, code is only working if I catch keyboard with the current active window of my program.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's null because your application does not have focus. You can create a dummy [System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, new HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", IntPtr.Zero), 0, key);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to dispose of the HwndSource?